# Compare two strings in C#

Tags: c#, string, compare

I store 2 serialized object in 2 text file and then i read both and store it in 2 different string, and try to compare this 2 strings, the comparison failed more then one time because of the carriage return and new line difference in the end of one of the string, 
how i could compare both with ignoring spaces or carriage returns, I know I can compress the 2 strings and compare them, but is there anything like done by .net library, Like Icomparer, I'm not sure if this will work for me too.

thank you in advance 
Jp

Comment: What language are you using? Post your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both values are stored as strings, the `String.Trim()` function will take care of your troublesome whitespace characters, or just compare whilst replacing the whitespace characters.

```
        string a = "string comparison\r\n";
        string b = "string comparison";

        string c = a.Trim();
        string d = b.Trim();

        if (c == d)
            Console.WriteLine("strings are equal");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("strings are not equal");

        string e = a.Replace("\r\n", "");
        string f = b.Replace("\r\n", "");

        if (e == f)
            Console.WriteLine("strings are equal");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("strings are not equal");
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick work around would be to replace all '\n' and '\r' character by nothing and then compare.

Comment: this is my plan B if no built in function for it

Comment: If there is any built in function, I bet they do replace. You can always create your own compareWithIgniore(string charToIgniore) function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading line by line, just ignore any characters that represent line breaks between them.
If you expect line breaks, simply convert to identical characters using a find and replace.

Comment: No i dont read line by line, I use readtoend function so it store the entire file into a string. and the only problem im facing is in the end of the file some sometime contain \r\n and some not and this why the comparison fails

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple Regular Expression that can eliminate the whitespace and compare (or do what Phillippe said). But I dont think there a built-in function to do that kind of comparison.

Comment: yeh this what I have in mind, i was wondering if there is any built in function

Comment: Sorry. I have not seen such a thing in .NET. There might be 3rd party libraries...